# Chart.js and right side free space

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I wanted to ask, if there is a way to push chart to right side, so there will not be any free space. I attached simple image, red line show, that this space should be filled also by chart.

Also is possible to create vertical lines as dots ? I can't find answers to my questions, on official doc.[image]

An this is my javsacript code:

```
 var lineChartData = {
                            labels : ["January","February","March","April"],
                            datasets : [
                                {
                                    label: "Dataset",   
                                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                    data : [0,3,4,11]
                                }
                            ]
                        };


                        window.onload = function(){
                            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {

                                responsive: true,
                                scaleOverride: true,
                                scaleSteps: Math.ceil((max-start)/step),
                                scaleStepWidth: step,
                                pointDot : false,
                            });
                        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is there because the last x axis label (April). Chart.js leaves enough space so that the label does not get clipped off. This also ensures that the tooltip for the last point shows without clipping off.

You could set the last (or all) labels to an empty string to get rid of the space. However, you won't see any labels in the tooltips. If you want to see the labels in the tooltips you need to extend the chart to remove the x axis labels like so

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        var labels = data.labels;
        data.labels = data.labels.map(function () { return '' });
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.datasets[0].points.forEach(function (point, i) {
            point.label = labels[i]
        })
    }
});
```

Note that you need to use LineAlt instead of Line.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/0u2c7tez/

However this will still clip off the tooltip for the last point. If you are going to enable tooltips and don't want them to be clipped off, then you need to use custom tooltips so that the tooltip is rendered in an external element (instead of the canvas) and not clipped off (see https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/line-customTooltips.html)

Comment: Great, full answer. Thank You.

Comment: So there is no way to show labels on the X axis and just have them get clipped/cropped at the end/right side?